# EM algorithm for complex likelihood?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, expectation-maximization

I want to maximize a likelihood function $L(\theta)$, $\theta \in {\mathbb R}^P$. The likelihood function has a complicated expression involving splines, and an numerical integral for each observation. Is there a general way to implement the EM algorithm for such model or the EM only works in nice cases where one can calculate conditionals and expectations?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without more detail about the problem you're working on. However, take a look at the many variants of [stochastic EM](http://faculty.vassar.edu/paruud/courses/simulation/Nielsen%20-%20Bernoulli%20-%20SEM.pdf), that use Monte Carlo methods/simulation to approximate the needed conditional expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EM algorithm is very general. The two steps are 1) compute a specific expectation and 2) maximize that expectation. Neither of those two steps put much restriction on what kinds of models can be fit with EM.

Now how computationally difficult those two steps are can vary dramatically. The more complicated your model the more computational complex one or both of those steps will be.